# CSS/jQuery maybe - Form text not visible in Safari on Mac

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms

Lataeviaberry.com contains a "GET IN TOUCH" form that functions in other browsers, but in safari only the `<textarea>` field accepts text. The `<input>` fields will not display any of the text typed into them. I have tried changing each instance of `-webkit-user-select: none;` to `-webkit-user-select: text;`, and even added the below block to my styles.css but nothing has worked.

```css
input [type=text]{
 -webkit-user-select: text !important;
 -khtml-user-select: text;
 -moz-user-select: text;
 -ms-user-select: text;
 user-select: text;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is the padding on `.contact .form-control`.

Or the set height on `.form-control`.

You can solve it in multiple ways.